# Confusion on the definition of a neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

So I've just started learning metric spaces and I'm getting a bit confused on some of the definitions namely the definition of a neighbourhood.
I looked quite a bit online and the definitions always seem to vary my main confusion is the epsilon ball around the point x a subset of the neighbourhood or a proper subset?.
A formal definition of a neighbourhood in a metric space would be helpful
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space and $p$ is a point in $X$, then a neighborhood of $p$ is a subset $V$ of $X$ that includes an open set $U$ containing $p$, that is, $p\in U\subseteq V\subseteq X$. Note that $V$ need not be open, but if it is, it is called an open neighborhood of $p$, however some require it to be open, so beware of what conventions you are using. This is also equivalent to $p$ being in the interior of $V$.

Comment: What about in a metric space

Comment: metric spaces are topological spaces.

Comment: Oh yes silly me but I mean is there a definition in terms of epsilon balls ?

Comment: set $U$ to be the epsilon ball.

Comment: Could $V$ and $U$ be the entire set $X$ then?

Comment: in some cases no, for example, $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, and in some cases yes, for example $(0,1)$ with the usual metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set $X$ is **open** if, for every point $x \in X$ in the set $X$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball $B_{\epsilon}(x) = \{ y : d(x,y) < \epsilon \} \subseteq X$ is contained in $X$.

An **open neighborhood of a point $x$** is any open set containing $x$. Some texts use this interchangeably with **neighborhood**. Others will define a **neighborhood of $x$** as any set that contains an open neighborhood of $x$.

For almost all the concepts you'll see in an introductory textbook, both definitions will yield the results, and the distinction does not matter.